# Can MySQL reboot the server its running on?

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am running a MySQL on Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2. I understand that the memory given to this instance is pretty small (actually 15G) for the kind of workload I run with MySQL. Few days back I noticed that server was rebooted. I checked `/var/log/messages`, `/var/log/kern.log` and then `lastlog`. I found out from the `last` command that the system was rebooted by the `reboot` pseudo-user.

The `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio` is set to 50, which means that the Linux will commit 50% more memory to the running processes. I have not created a swap, so I am sure that at times, MySQL will request for more memory than the available physical RAM which it won't get. Also, I have not set kernel panic in the `/etc/sysctl.conf`. This instance is used as a database server and no other processes other than a cron (used to backup MySQL data) that runs every hour. The cron was not scheduled to run at the time when the reboot happened.

So, my question is -

Can a overloaded MySQL reboot the instance it is running on when it ran out of memory?

I am trying to understand what might have led to the server reboot.

Comment: That is never the case with EC2 instance, Your instance will freez up but never reboot.  MySQL does not have any priviledges as well to do reboot. Unless you explicity do a reboot or have a recover instance option enable in cloudwatch alarm.

Comment: Sysadmins or DBAs would be in a lot better position to answer this question than sw developers.